# Which is the TNG episode where "time warp" is considered as a means of travel?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, which episode talks about "time warp" as a means of travel?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it was TNG? The [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Time_warp) page on time warp doesn't mention any TNG episode. Maybe it was the TOS episode *The Cage*?

Comment: @randal'thor - That was my first thought - *"Time Warp Factor 7"*

Comment: Let's do the time warp again!! Sorry, I was channelling Rocky Horror.

Answer (score 16):

There are no references to "time warp" in *TNG*.  You may be confusing this with the *Deep Space Nine* episode ["Little Green Men"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/480.htm):

> **ROM:** If we find a sufficiently powerful energy source, we should be able to trigger a temporal surge in the subspace continuum and recreate the same kind of **time warp** that brought us here in the first place.

Given the appearance of Worf in the episode and the proximity in time to *TNG*, it would be easy to confuse it for a *TNG* episode.

Answer (score 10):

As rand al'thor suggested in a comment, I suspect you are confusing *TNG* with the original series. In the pilot episode ["The Cage"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cage_(episode)) (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/1.htm)), captain Pike at one point says "Our destination is the Talos star group. Our time warp factor seven." And later, a member of Pike's landing team named Tayler is talking to an Earthling who's been stranded on a distant planet for many years, and says "And you won't believe how fast you can get back. Well the time barrier's been broken. Our new ships can--" (his thought is interrupted by the sight of a beautiful woman). Finally, later in the episode Spock is the acting Captain, and he says "All decks prepare for hyperdrive. Time warp factor--" (he is interrupted by someone telling him the ship's controls have gone dead).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hypnosifl's answer, in TOS and later in Star Trek IV Spock specifically makes calculations for time warp.

In the TOS episode "Tomorrow is Yesterday" the Enterprise was pulled into the past by a black star and needed to calculate a time warp to return to the 23rd century.

In Star Trek IV - the voyage home - Kirk orders Spock to calculate a time warp to take the stolen Klingon ship back in time to find humpback whales